# flutter json_serializable missing file

Tags: json, flutter, dart, json-serializable, json-annotation

i don't seem to understand why it is showing the error i have created two different .g.dart files

but for this file it shows missing part.
[WARNING] json_serializable:json_serializable on lib/Model/Supermodel.dart:
Missing "part 'Supermodel.g.dart';".

```
import 'package:flutter_app/Model/addproductmodel.dart';
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'SuperModel.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class SuperModel {
  List<addproductmodel> data;
  SuperModel({this.data});
  factory SuperModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$SuperModelFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$SuperModelToJson(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "g" in ".g.dart"  stands for generated.
You are not supposed to create them yourself. Instead you can generate them using
[build_runner](https://pub.dev/packages/build_runner) for example:

```
flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

This will generate the missing files.

Comment: The Supermodel.g.dart file is not created yet . Its showing  Succeeded after 86ms with 0 outputs (0 actions)

Answer (score 0):

Probably an old question to answer and got me here looking for an answer to similar situation.

What I did notice for my fix and I believe it is the same in your case, is that file naming is case sensitive. Considering your model file name is `Supermodel.dart` your part name should be `part 'Supermodel.g.dart';` instead of `part 'SuperModel.g.dart';`

The same case sensitive name is evident in the warning message too.

Answer (score 0):

1- check the name of the file is it the same with capital and small letter  .
2- click on `Ctrl + s`  before run the commend .

Answer (score 0):

Generated file name should be same like your file name, not same like class name.it is case sensitive also.